# Python - return a region of a list based on calculated percentages

Tags: python, list

I have a fairly long list in python which I want to return parts of it in a single, shorter list based on 3 percentages. If the first percentage was 30%, it would need to return the first 30% of the values and if the 3rd percentage was 50% it would need to return the last half of the values of my long list.

This is what I have so far, it has issues with rounding and is an ugly solution

```
  class OM():
    def __init__(self,name):
      self.name = name
      self.total = 120
      self.a = 21
      self.b = 34
      self.c = 65

    def hRange(self,action):
      if self.total > 0:
        a_perc = int(self.a / float(self.total) *169)
        b_perc = int(self.b / float(self.total) *169)
        c_perc = int(self.c / float(self.total) *169)
        if action=='a': return lst[:aperc]
        elif action=='b': return lst[a_perc:a_perc+b_perc]
        elif action=='c': return lst[-c_perc:]

      else:
        raise Exception
```

I realise this isn't well coded at all, (hard coded the lst length as 169, doesn't catch different actions etc etc) I just wanted to help explain what I was trying to do.

In my actual implementation the values total,a,b,c would be initialised at 0 and another method would update them, as they're just tallys. I just set them as some random values here so the code returns percentages.

I would be hugely appreciative if anyone could give me any advice on how to go about doing this a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got carried away with a general solution...  I belive this should handle all cases:

```
def split_list(mylist, *args):
    ilist = map(lambda p : int(p * len(mylist) / 100.0), args) + [len(mylist)]
    return reduce(lambda l, v : [l[0] + [mylist[l[1]:v]], v], ilist, [[],0])[0]
```

The function takes a list and a list of percentage split points (in order) and returns you the lists as you need them.  Handles cases where there are more percentages of splits than items in the list.

Comment: Wow, Thank you! That's very impressive! I've since read up on map, reduce, filter, lambda and list comprehension. Firstly to understand how this function works and secondly because they're very useful!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep three lists, based on a certain percentage at the start and end plus the "in between":

```
def split_list(mylist, a, b):
    l = len(mylist)
    return ( mylist[:int(a*l/100)], 
             mylist[int(a*l/100):-int(b*l/100)],
             mylist[-int(b*l/100):] )
```

where a and b are the percentages (given from 0 to 100). It's nearly the same implementation as yours, but you only need to use two percentages (if the middle list is the remaining part when both ends are trimmed off). I will leave it up to you to incorporate this in your code...

Comment: Ah Thank you, you're right- I do only need the two percentages and in fact I don't need to tally c or the total at all.

Im just realising my percentage variables aren't even percentages, i was a very poor attempt :P

Comment: Yes, the only thing you want to add is a mechanism for checking that the percentages don't go over 100%, and depending on your needs, that they don't overlap (i.e. a = 65, b = 65).